# JSS CLI commands with --config switch

Tags: jss, sitecore-cli

I'm trying to use the JSS CLI to deploy content and components to my local CM instance running in Docker, but with a different config file. Normally I run `jss deploy files` or `jss deploy app` and it works as expected, but if I try `jss deploy files --config "./scjssconfig.test.json"` I get prompted to configure a connection as if the config file doesn't exist.

Note the `scjssconfig.test.json` file is just the standard `scjssconfig.json` file with the name changed.

I've tried different combinations of paths for the config file - backslashes, foreslashes, fully specified, relative, moving the config file to another directory - but nothing works.

Has anyone gotten the JSS CLI to work with the `--config` switch?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy the scjssconfig.test.json file into Sitecore instance?

Comment: No I'm not trying to deploy/copy the scjssconfig.test.json file into Sitecore. Instead I want to have a different config file with slightly different settings (ex. different 'layoutServiceHost' for CI/CD in a cloud hosted environment.)